# AngularJS - Handling dynamic flows

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm pretty new to using AngularJS and maybe thinking so far in my first project, so your help will be really appreciated.

I'm trying to find the best way to create a dynamic flow of different pages, for example:

> #### *Reading from a JSON file*:
>
> ```
>  {    
>     id: 1,
>     name: "Flow 1",
>     steps: ["page1","page2","page3","page4"] 
>  },{    
>     id: 2,
>     name: "Flow 2",
>     steps: ["page3","page1","page4","page2"] 
>  }
> ```
>
> So, if I am in "Flow 2", in "page1", if I click "Next", I'll go to "page4"

I don't know if the JSON file would be the best approach, but I'm looking for a solution that can render complex flows in a really easy way. I want to be able to make changes and test them as fast as I can.

I've tried to do that in the main controller but I'm kind of frustrated since I'm not getting a proper solution, so if you guys can give me some thoughts on it, it would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I would proably set up a service/factory to handle the flows and then let the controller "ask" the service what links to attach to the next-button

Comment: @NilsLarson Thanks for this! Do you mean reading a JSON file from the service/factory? 

Also, if the url is (http:localhost/2/page3) I have to know that I'm in "Flow 2 - page3", so from here, should I read the hash value from the controller and then get the flow from the service/factory? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a valid solution.. and also you could build some sort of parsing-function in the service.. so that in routingconfig of your module you define certain steps as parameters (routeParams), and pass them into your service when the controller kicks in.